# How to create an Encoder for Scala collection (to implement custom Aggregator)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-encoders

Spark 2.3.0 with Scala 2.11.  I'm implementing a custom `Aggregator` according to the docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#type-safe-user-defined-aggregate-functions).  The aggregator requires 3 types for input, buffer, and output.

My aggregator has to act upon all previous rows in the window so I declared it like this:

```
case class Foo(...)

object MyAggregator extends Aggregator[Foo, ListBuffer[Foo], Boolean] {
    // other override methods
    override def bufferEncoder: Encoder[ListBuffer[Mod]] = ???
}
```

One of the override methods is supposed to return the encoder for the buffer type, which in this case is a `ListBuffer`.  I can't find any suitable encoder for `org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders` nor any other way to encode this so I don't know what to return here.

I thought of creating a new case class which has a single property of type `ListBuffer[Foo]` and using that as my buffer class, and then using `Encoders.product` on that, but I am not sure if that is necessary or if there is something else I am missing.  Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Just analyzing what you said to understand things better. _"My aggregator has to act upon all previous rows in the window so I declared it like this:"_ does it make any difference whether your aggregator acts upon previous rows or any rows? Just curious how important this is.

Comment: In my use case say there are 5 rows, the result for row 1 depends on row 1, the result for row 2 depends on rows 1 and 2, the result for row 3 depends on 1-3, etc . This depends on a specific row sort. If every row depended on all other rows I guess I'd have to do this in 2 passes, first to collect all of the values for the window with collect_list or collect_set, and another pass to calculate the aggregated values.

Comment: Isn't that window aggregation and the requirement of "previous rows" a window specification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just let Spark SQL do its work and find the proper encoder using `ExpressionEncoder` as follows:

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.3.0

case class Mod(id: Long)

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder

scala> val enc: Encoder[ListBuffer[Mod]] = ExpressionEncoder()
enc: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Mod]] = class[value[0]: array<struct<id:bigint>>]
```

Comment: Thank you that is remarkably simple and appears to work. The encoder that is implicitly created is not one that I could have created explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see anything in org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders that could be used to directly encode a ListBuffer, or for that matter even a List

One option seems to be going with putting it in a case class, as you suggested:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

case class Foo(field: String)
case class Wrapper(lb: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Foo])
Encoders.product[Wrapper]
```

Another option could be to use kryo:

```
Encoders.kryo[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Foo]]
```

Or finally you could look at ExpressionEncoders, which extend Encoder:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
ExpressionEncoder[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Foo]]
```

This is the best solution, as it keeps everything transparent to catalyst and therefore allows it to do all of its wonderful optimisations.

One thing I noticed whilst having a play:

```
ExpressionEncoder[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Foo]].schema == ExpressionEncoder[List[Foo]].schema
```

I haven't tested any of the above whilst executing aggregations, so there may be runtime issues. Hope this is helpful.